# Pythonic Way To Test All Combinations Of Function Parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, combinations

I have a *given* function (which I cannot change) of the form:

```
def foo(bar=False, baz=False, ban=False, baf=False, bal=False):
    ...
```

In some [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) code, I'd like to perform tests on all the 2<sup>5</sup> calls:

```
foo(bar=False, baz=False, ban=False, baf=False, bal=False)
foo(bar=False, baz=False, ban=False, baf=False, bal=True)
foo(bar=False, baz=False, ban=False, baf=True, bal=False)
foo(bar=False, baz=False, ban=False, baf=True, bal=True)
...
foo(bar=True, baz=True, ban=True, baf=True, bal=True)
```

(for the sake of the question, run each call, and `assertEqual` that the result is 10.)

What is a pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: `itertools.product(((False, True),)*5)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You forgot to unpack the tuple; it should be `itertools.product(*((False, True),)*5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
import itertools
for combination in itertools.product(*[(True, False)]*5):
    assertEqual(foo(*combination), 10)
```